# Pixi.js Sound Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

i am having some trouble. for some reason this simple function doesnt work. I hope someone can help out

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@pixi/sound": "^5.2.1",
"@pixi/ui": "^0.9.0",
"pixi.js": "^7.3.1"
}
```

imported pixi/sound like this:

`import { sound } from '@pixi/sound';`

app.js line 160, which causes the problem:

```
sound.Sound.from({
    url: 'music/theme.mp3',
    autoPlay: true,
    complete: function() {
        console.log('Sound finished');
    }
});
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'from')
at title_screen (app.js:160:14)
at app.js:292:1
```

I just cant find the error.

```
sound.add('my_sound', 'music/theme.mp3');
sound.play('my_sound');
```

this works, but i thought that using Sound instead of sound would be the correct way of doing this.

I hope somebody can help

I tried importing `* as sound`  and then using it with PIXI. in front.
But nothing worked